# How do i determine the size of an array from a character read from a file?

Tags: c

I have to allocate a dynamic array and i know how many columns there will be on the array but i don't know how many rows, all i have is a number on a .txt file. I have tried the following code but i am not sure it will work:

```
int x = (int)fgetc(file)-48;
```

Since the ascii value of 0 is 48, i assumned that i needed to cast the character read from the file in order to be able to use it as my rows number.

I assume i should be able to allocate the array the 2D array as it follows:

```
m = (int **)malloc(x*sizeof(int*));
for (i=0;i<x;i++)
{
    m[i] = (int*)malloc(10*sizeof(int));
}
```

Am i correct? Any help will be highly apretiated.

Comment: So `x` can only be `[0, 9]` then?

Comment: @Jackd haven't thought about it. It is suppossed to be a value between 0 and 1000. Now i am pretty sure it wont work. I guess i will have to save it on an array `int x[4]` and do the type casting for each `x[i]`.

Comment: x[5] -- add a null character after the last digit you've added.  Then you can use strtol() or atoi() to get the integer.

Comment: This question cannot be adequately answered without knowing more about what your input looks like.

Comment: if you have a number between 0-1000, then you could use `fscanf` to read it from the file

Comment: I see that you swear about stackoverflow in your tweets and are unhappy about the suggestion by other users here that you ought to learn how to use a debugger. I have two remarks about that: **1.** **Do** learn using a debugger. It is an indispensible tool for software development. On top of that being versed in gdb is a skill skill that will give you an advantage above others. 2. The reason for being criticised here are that you didn't seem to put enough effort in a solution of your own, or (here) that you would like others to help you but don't prepare your question adequately.

Comment: @PeterSchneider If you went trough my previous questions you might have noticed that i have put more effort into presenting the relevant parts of the code only. Also i have made a more specific question this time. I look for information on previous questions and do some (mostly google) research before asking and the last thing i want is the kind of automated response "learn how to use a debugger". I have never been taught how to use a debugger, thanks to you now at least i know it is called gdb. Thank you for that.

Comment: Instead of writing that you should have provided us with the format of the file, or an example file, or the assignment. "Debugger": sometimes the last wanted reply is the most helpful ;-).

Answer (score 0):

You can design a list and dynamically insert your rows.

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand correctly that your file looks like

```
327            // number of lines
1 2 3          // line 1
33 44 55       // line 2
```

... repeats until 327 lines have been printed, all with 3 elements? Note that the line breaks would be optional and could be any whitespace.

The canonical way to read a number from text in C is using scanf. scanf uses, like printf, a weird looking format string as the fist parameter. Each basic type has a letter associated with it, for integers it's d or, more intuitively, i. These letters are prefixed with a %. So to read an integer, you would write `scanf("%d", &lines);` if lines is an int holding the number of lines. (Do rather not use x, for readability).

The way you allocate your array is correct (provided x holds the number of lines and 10 is the known line length). One style issue is that the 10 should be #defined as a macro so that you can use e.g. malloc(LINE_LEN*sizeof(int)). That helps later when that number should ever change and you have (in a real world program) scattered references to m over several source files.

If this is just a little program and the array isnt't inordinately large and does not need to live longer than the function call (which, in the case of main(), may be long enough in any case), the easiest would be to use a variable size array in C; provided you use a modestly modern compiler:

```
#define LINE_LEN 10
int lineCount;
scanf("%d", &lineCount);
int m[lineCount][LINE_LEN];
// fill from file
```

If you compile with gcc you'll probably need to specify "-std=c99" as a command line option for that.

Comment: What if it looks like this: `327|1,2,3|33,44,55`? Thats why I say above we need to know what the input looks like.

Comment: My suggestion would still work ;-). Apart from that, assuming the common and most simple case seems reasonable, if only for good old Occam. That said, yes, the OP could help us a bit more. E.g. he could provide the original assignment if he expects us to help him with it.

Comment: You wanted to say `scanf("%d", &lines)`, not `%s` I believe.

Answer (score 0):

First off fgetc() returns an integer, so casting it as an int will do nothing.  Second you're only reading in one integer at a time with fgetc() so you will have a 1 digit number in x.

Your array allocation looks correct, but you can also allocate the columns as an array of int * on the stack and then allocate the rows dynamically as m[i] = (int*)malloc(x*sizeof(int)); from i = 0->9

Comment: Strictly spoken you are reading in one **char**. scanf( "%d"...) reads in  an int ;-) And just _why_ the getc family returns an int is left as an excercise ;-).